# C# How to change the drive letter of the CDROM from D: to Z:

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, wmi

I am trying to write a metod that will change the CDROM drive from letter D to letter Z and not having any luck with WMI. Is there some other way that I can do this using C#?

```
public void setVolCDROM()
{
    SelectQuery queryCDROM = 
        new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_cdromdrive");
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcherCDROM = 
        new ManagementObjectSearcher(queryCDROM);
    foreach(ManagementObject cdromLetter in searcherCDROM.Get())
    {
        MessageBox.Show(cdromLetter["Drive"].ToString() + "\n"
            + cdromLetter["Manufacturer"].ToString());
        if (cdromLetter["Drive"].ToString() == "D:")
        {
            cdromLetter["Drive"] = "Z:";                        
            cdromLetter.Put();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I don't know about WMI, but you can change the drive letter with winapi, here is an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364014%28VS.85%29.aspx) that I ported (just the part you need) to C#

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint(string
    lpszVolumeMountPoint, [Out] StringBuilder lpszVolumeName,
    uint cchBufferLength);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool DeleteVolumeMountPoint(string lpszVolumeMountPoint);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool SetVolumeMountPoint(string lpszVolumeMountPoint,
    string lpszVolumeName);

const int MAX_PATH = 260;

private void ChangeDriveLetter()
{
    StringBuilder volume = new StringBuilder(MAX_PATH);
    if (!GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint(@"D:\", volume, (uint)MAX_PATH))
        Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error());

    if (!DeleteVolumeMountPoint(@"D:\"))
        Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error());

    if (!SetVolumeMountPoint(@"Z:\", volume.ToString()))
        Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error());
}
```

Be careful running this code, you have to delete the drive mount point before assigning it to a new letter, this could lead to problems, from the original code:

```
/*****************************************************************
WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING  

   This program will change drive letter assignments, and the    
   changes persist through reboots. Do not remove drive letters  
   of your hard disks if you do not have this program on floppy  
   disk or you might not be able to access your hard disks again!
*****************************************************************/
```

Comment: I also find enjoyable the reference to `floppy disks` in the warning notice.

Comment: At first I thought you were commenting on the poster's post... then I noticed you *are* the poster. lol, +1

Comment: This is a great alternative when WMI isn't otherwise available

Answer (score 5):

jason, you can use the [`Win32_Volume`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394515%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class

try this code

```
    ManagementObjectSearcher disks = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_Volume WHERE DriveLetter = 'D:'");
    foreach (ManagementObject disk in disks.Get())
    {
        disk.Get();
        disk["DriveLetter"] = "Z:";
        disk.Put();
    }
```

Comment: I tried this with a regular drive, and it worked, except it made two drive letters! The original was F:/ and I ended up with F:/ and Z:/.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Rodrigo! That was exactly what I was looking for. I just added some wmi code infront of it so that I could make sure I was grabbing the CDROM drive.

```
public void setCDROM(){
                SelectQuery queryCDROM =
                        new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_cdromdrive");
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcherCDROM =
                        new ManagementObjectSearcher(queryCDROM);
                int i = 0;
                foreach(ManagementObject cdromLetter in searcherCDROM.Get())
                {
                    // if stement in place to handle if there is more than one cdrom drive
                    // this will only handle the first cdrom drive encountered 
                    i = i + 1;
                    if (i == 1)
                    {
                        // run the ChangeDriveLetter method passing the drive letter string
                        ChangeDriveLetter(cdromLetter["Drive"].ToString());
                    }
                }
}
```

Comment: Be sure to confirm that you are passing the drive with the backslash at the end `D:\\` and I also think it must be uppercase

Answer (score 0):

I think WMI's SelectQueries are supposed to only read/query information and not to perform any update. I can be wrong but I think to change the drive letter you should go lower in some Win32 Api...

Comment: hi Davide,Yeah I can change the label information using this code, but not the actual drive letter. Lokking for an example on how to do this. I am a C# noob :)

Comment: WMI can change data, but not for everything.

Comment: -1 Davide, with the `WMI` depending of the class and the namespace you can query, update and insert(create) data.

Answer (score 0):

See [IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_CREATE_POINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560457.aspx).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to add a note to rodrigoq's solution, that in Vista and up, you will need to run your app with elevated privileges otherwise you will not be able to delete the mount point and assign it a new drive letter which will cause an exception to be thrown.